# How to retrieve object from runtime environment?

Tags: r, runtime, environment

Say I have an object defined within a function:

```
foo <- function(){
  bar <- c("list", "of", "object", "values")
}
```

How can I retrieve this object from the ephemeral runtime environment created when executing the function?

I understand that I could edit the function to assign this object to a permanent, named environment using `<<-` or `assign()` - or, more crudely, just copy-paste the desired text from the function body - but I'm looking for a programmatic solution which obviates the need to modify the function.

Comment: It is unclear what you want to achieve. Using your example, what would be the desired output?

Comment: The list that is passed to bar is not really in the environment of foo.

Comment: Are you looking for `return(bar)`? Otherwise, please elaborate!

Comment: Sorry for any lack of clarity. The output I seek is an object called "bar", which is a character vector containing elements "list" "of" "object" "values". I want this returned to a permanent environment other than runtime (e.g. the global environment). The answer below satisfies this. Thanks all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pass `bar` to the caller one normally returns it.  In the example function it would be:

```
bar <- foo()
```

If `bar` were an intermediate result in `foo` which is not returned then use `trace`:

```
trace(foo, exit = quote(bar <<- bar))
## [1] "foo"

foo()
## Tracing foo() on exit 

untrace(foo)

bar
## [1] "list"   "of"     "object" "values"
```